# What is the best way to internationalize a Python app with multiple i18n domains?

Tags: python, localization, internationalization

I'm internationalizing a Python application, with two goals in mind:

1. The application loads classes from multiple packages, each with its own i18n domain.  So modules in package A are using domain A, modules in package B are using domain B, etc.
2. The locale can be changed while the application is running.

Python's `gettext` module makes internationalizing a single-domain single-language application very easy; you just set the locale, then call `gettext.install()`, which finds the right `Translation` and installs its `ugettext` method in the global namespace as `_`.  But obviously a global value only works for a single domain, and since it loads a single `Translation`, it only works for that locale.

I could instead load the `Translation` at the top of each module, and bind its ugettext method as `_`.  Then each module would be using the `_` for its own domain.  But this still breaks when the locale is changed, because `_` is for the wrong locale.

So I guess I could load the correct `ugettext` at the top of every function, but that seems awfully cumbersome.  An alternative would be to still do it per-module, but instead of binding `ugettext`, I would substitute my own function, which would check the current locale, get its `Translation`, and forward the string to it.  Does anyone have a cleaner solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about you bind _ to a function roughly like this (for each module):

```
def _(message):
    return my_gettext(__name__, message)
```

This allows you to use gettext while at the same time perform any lookup on a per-module-per-call-base that allows you to switch locale as well.